# drawing a circle with bitmapData

Tags: phaser-framework

My understanding is its preferable to use a bitmapData object to add graphics which you will manipulate with the physics engine.

So, I've been trying to draw circles with bitmapData objects.

I've tried two method which have both failed for different reasons.

1) I followed this example: http://phaser.io/exa...from-bitmapdata

replacing rect with circle as document here: http://phaser.io/doc...ta.html#circle:

var bmd = game.add.bitmapData(128,128);

```
// draw to the canvas context like normal
bmd.ctx.beginPath();
bmd.ctx.circle(0,0,128);
bmd.ctx.fillStyle = '#ff0000';
bmd.ctx.fill();
```

The rect method demonstrated in the example works fine for me, but when I change it to circle as I have above it gives an error: undefined is not a function, on this line: bmd.ctx.circle(0,0,128);

Also, this confuses me because, is that both circle and rect are listed as public methods of bitmapdata, not of ctx.

I also do not understand the difference between bitmapData.context and bitmapData.ctx

2)  I coded this following an example I found online:

```
    bmd.ctx.fillStyle = '#999999';
    bmd.ctx.beginPath();
    bmd.ctx.arc(25, 25, 100, 0, 2*Math.PI, true); 
    bmd.ctx.fill();
```

this produces only a quarter of a circle, despite being set to the amount of radians of a full circle.

Answer (score 2):

1)

- BitmapData creates a canvas object.
- BitmapData.context refers to the 2dcontext of that canvas.

  With that said :
- [BitmapData.ctx is a reference of BitmapData.context](http://phaser.io/docs/2.3.0/Phaser.BitmapData.html#ctx)
- [Circle is a helper method provided by BitmapData](http://phaser.io/docs/2.3.0/Phaser.BitmapData.html#circle). You get an 'undefined' error because you are calling it from BitmapData.ctx and not from BitmapData directly.
- You got confused because the canvas object itself [has a .rect() method](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/canvas_rect.asp),
  while bitmapData [got one too](http://phaser.io/docs/2.3.0/Phaser.BitmapData.html#rect) but slightly different.
  That's why bmd.ctx.rect() works but bmd.ctx.circle() doesn't.

2) The reason you see a quarter only is because you set the bitmapData size too  small (128 x 128) for the circle you are asking Phaser to draw.
You are placing the center of the circle at  {x:25, y:25} and draw with a 100px radius, thus getting out of space.

Lower the radius, place the center at the center of the bitmapData's context you created, and you will see the correct result:

```
 bmd.ctx.arc(bmd.width / 2, bmd.height / 2, 50, 0, 2 * Math.PI, true);
```